# writing error when nothing returned from tuple within list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, nested-lists

```
tup_list = [(111, 'red'), (222, 'blue'), (333, 'green'), (444, 'red')]
x = input(str("colour? "))
for c in tup_list:
    if x in c:
        print(c[0])
    else:
        print("error ")
```

---

Example of code^

If user inputs "red", output is:

```
111
error
error
444
```

If user inputs "blue", output is:

```
error
222
error
error
```

Etc. If user inputs "randomchars" (any random characters) not in tup_list, output is:

```
error
error
error
error
```

I understand that my code is printing "error" for each c in tup_list. I would like my code to write "error" a single time if the user input is not within tup_list. I also don't understand why errors are being printed for each negative match within the tup_list (e.g. inputting red gets 111 and 444 correctly, but it also gives two errors for the blue and yellow tuples).

Comment: that's expected: if match, it prints else it prints error... have you considered using a dictionary with the color names as keys and the numbers as values (as lists so more than 1 can be associated to 1 color)? it would avoid a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is printing `'error'` for each `c` in `tup_list` it doesn't match because you're iterating over each `c` in `tup_list`. In each iteration, you're checking if the color matches, and in each iteration you print whether it matches (the code number) or not (`'error'`). You could have a boolean variable to verify if it matched or not:

```py
tup_list = [(111, 'red'), (222, 'blue'), (333, 'green'), (444, 'red')]
x = input('colour? ')

match = False
for c in tup_list:
    if x in c:
        print(c[0])
        match = True

if not match:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Thanks! All the other solutions worked too, but this one was the most simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here we gather the list of matched items first, then print them or error.

```
tup_list = [(111, 'red'), (222, 'blue'), (333, 'green'), (444, 'red')]
x = input("colour? ")
matches = [c for c in tup_list if x in c]
if matches:
    print('\n'.join(m[0] for m in matches))
else:
    print("error")
```

(I also replaced `str("colour? ")` with `"colour? "`: it's already a string, no need to cast it)

Comment: The code could be improved if the list `matches` was composed only of the number codes, so `[c[1] for c in tup_list if x in c]`. That way, you don't need a loop `if matches` - `print('\n'.join(matches))`

Comment: @YanOrestes You are right. But I rewrited my code in slightly other way to demonstrate a bit different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `if/else` statement in the for loop, either it finds a match for the color, or it prints an error. If you want to print all matches and only print `error` once, you need a slightly different branching structure.

I'd recommend:

```
tup_list = [(111, 'red'), (222, 'blue'), (333, 'green'), (444, 'red')]

matches = []

x = input(str("colour? "))
for c in tup_list:
    if x in c:
        matches.append(c[0])

if matches:
    print("\n".join(map(str, matches)))
else:
     print("error")
```

Note that I have to map each of the matches from int to str since join() expects a list of strings.